# IAP Auto Renewable Subscription manual renewal before expiry date

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewing

I am working on a app on **IAP Auto Renewable Subscription** which auto renews subscription after its expiry date.

I gave a renew button to renew a subscription if it is already expired. *(Auto Renewable Subscription might expire if user has canceled it from his iTunes account.)* So here are few cases:

1. what will happen if Auto Renewable Subscription is **running** and user is still trying to renew it by mistake.
2. what will happen if Auto Renewable Subscription is **stopped** from user's iTunes account and user is trying to renew it before it expires.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only answer your 1st question.

If a user has an Auto Renewable Subscription running, and tries to buy a 2nd one, StoreKit will abort the purchase, telling that the user already has one, via an alert view.

For your 2nd item (and the 1st), I recommend you to try in [sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH1-SW1) mode by creating test user on iTunesConnect "Manage User -> Test User"

Hope that helps...

Comment: Oh! How I forgot that iTunes alerts itself if subscription is already running. You are right. 2nd question can not be tested in sandbox mode, because a subscription can not be stopped if it was done in sandbox mode. We can not manage sandbox subscription.